# Iphone add task to EDT ? something like SwingUtilities.invokeLater ?

Tags: iphone

is there a way to add something to be executed in EDT/Event Dispatch Thread in Iphone application like the invokeLater method in Java Swing application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `NSObject` class reference - methods starting with performSelector

Answer (score 0):

I want me too some code part.

This is unfortunately not doing the desired behavior:

```
- (void) invokeLater_aux:(NSArray*)functionName_arg 
{
    NSLog(@"invokeLater_aux:" );
    if(functionName_arg != nil && (functionName_arg.count > 0 )){
        // split the params:
        NSString* functionNameString = [functionName_arg objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSLog(@"functionNameString: %@",functionNameString);      
        SEL functionName = NSSelectorFromString( functionNameString);        

        id arg = nil;
        if(functionName_arg.count > 1){
            arg = [functionName_arg objectAtIndex:1];
        }

        // call the function on main thread
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:functionName withObject:arg waitUntilDone:YES ];    
    }
    [functionName_arg release];
}

- (void) invokeLater: (SEL)functionName withObject:(id)arg
{
    NSLog(@"invoke later: %@",NSStringFromSelector(functionName));
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(invokeLater_aux:) 
                           withObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       NSStringFromSelector(functionName),//the function name as String
                                       arg,// the function arguments
                                       nil]
     ];    
}
```

because it is start a new thread in invokeLater and doesn't wait to finish the execution the main thread and it will be executed the invokeLater_aux's call in the main thread ( at context switching?)

it is possible to have `n` threads with this code if you call `n` times the `invokeLater`.

- how to wait in `invokeLater_aux` , **until the main thread is finished**?